# Aggregate of activity duration in Drupal Views

Tags: drupal-views

I am trying to build a view that displays each CiviCRM contact and the sum of the duration of all their recorded activities. 
I would also like to distinguish contacts in the view whom's duration sum is greater than x minute either with an icon or different color or font.

Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we managed to accomplish this. 
- I used a module called views_aggregator to display the sum total duration of all the activities for each contact 
- I then created another view and did the same but filtered the results to only show contact with a total activity duration > x and rewrote the results to only display a badge
- then used the module views_field_view to display the badge from view2 next to the corresponding name in view1

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a Drupal question - you can do what you're looking for with the [Views Conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional) module.

Comment: Thanks for recommending that module. It does trigger based on the duration field but NOT based on the sum of the duration field. 
I am using views_aggregator to give me a total sum of all activity durations.
Any other ideas to work around this?

Comment: Consider either the [Computed Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field) module to create hidden fields to trigger on, or writing a module that injects 2-3 lines of jQuery?